# Git manage/merge remote branches from local host

Tags: git, merge, pull, multiple-projects

I am working on a project with other developers and a designer. When it comes to style up the project, I can not work on anything else but wait for designer to finish. What I tried to do, and I am half way there, is:

1. I set up a Vhost for designer, "different" project different url.
2. I copied my project to designer_folder.
3. I did git init, and add my (developer_folder) as remote.

What I failed to do is, pull on designer_project specific_branch all changes from specific_branch of my developer_project. 
I want to have a project just for him so he can play around with it and in the end I will pull changes from my project. 
Every time he will start working on something, I will create a new branch on his project, and merge my changes then pull his changes to my project.

Just for the comments, I googled and looked in stackoverflow. I just could not find one to work.

I am struggling. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bare repository for it.
Add a folder that you can both access, go into it and call

```
git init --bare
```

Then you both use that as a remote

```
git remote add local path/to/created/folder
```

You can now push and pull to that. So now that you have connected two remotes (origin probably and local) , you can also still push and pull to the other remote everybody else is working with.